# Passing parameters to pytest BOTH fixture and test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm using a python fixture `browser_manager` from a library which it would be inconvenient to modify or wrap in another class. `browser_manager` takes some variable `some_config`, which is passed to this fixture by `indirect`.

```py
@pytest.fixture(name="browser_manager")
def _browser_manager(request)
    indirect_params = getattr(request, "param", dict())
    return BrowserManager(indirect_params)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "browser_manager",
    [(some_config)],
    indirect=["browser_manager"]
    )
def test_browser_manager(browser_manager):
    # some test goes here
```

My question is how can I access `some_config` in the test function itself? `some_config` is successfully passed to the fixture. I could simply pass `some_config` in twice, but I want to avoid that for maintainability. As mentioned before, it would be inconvenient to modify the fixture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer was actually right above in my question. I made use of the fixture's request.

```py
@pytest.fixture(name="browser_manager")
def _browser_manager(request)
    indirect_params = getattr(request, "param", dict())
    return BrowserManager(indirect_params)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "browser_manager",
    [{"attribute": value}],
    indirect=["browser_manager"]
)
def test_browser_manager(browser_manager):
    attr_value = getattr(browser_manager.request, "param", dict()).get("attribute")
```